# Binary Search Issue

Tags: java, binary-search

I am currently working on the final part of a programming project for class. The program must take user input of 2 - 10 characters (letters only) and create all possible permutations recursively then cross check with a dictionary file whether the words are valid and print the valid words.

The binary search function seems to be working fine when I print it out during testing but when I try to implement a for loop to remove the invalid words, things get weird.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (Dictionary.binarySearch(dictionary, words.get(i), 0, dictionary.size() - 1) == -1) {
            words.remove(i);
        }
```

I tried to double check what is going on by transferring the return on the binary search function to another array i.e

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (Dictionary.binarySearch(dictionary, words.get(i), 0, dictionary.size() - 1) != -1) {
            indices.add(Dictionary.binarySearch(dictionary, words.get(i), 0, dictionary.size()-1));
            System.out.println(indices.get(i));
        }
```

When I print out the results of the binary search function for the instance that the user inputs e,a,t for example I get:

20949
22814
22813
-1
-1
899
3812
3786
-1
69054
-1
68389
68256
-1

which is exactly what I am looking for

but when I print out the arrayList indices, it comes up as:

[20949, 20949, 20949, 20949, 20949, 20949, 20949, 20949, 20949, 20949, 22814]

So if someone could help me get rid of the words in the arrayList "words" based on what the binarySearch function returns I would really appreciate it.

Thanks for any help and critique in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is here:

```
words.remove(i);
```

When you do that, words has one less element, and `words.get(i)` (before `i` is incremented) will return the next value.  However, you are incrementing `i`, so you are skipping that element.

The two common solutions for this are to either decrement `i` and `length` after removing the element, or start `i` at `length - 1` and decrement it till you get to 0.

Comment: thanks for the input but now I am experiencing an out of bounds error. I have also tried, instead of removing the word that is invalid, adding the validated word to a new arrayList which returns multiple copies of the same word so I don't think that this is the issue.

Comment: @EndlessProgression:  I'm guessing you tried the first option I suggested.  You also have to decrement length in that case if you aren't pulling it from the array each time.  Answer updated.

Comment: @EndlessProgression:  Also, you won't get duplicates unless you have duplicates in `words`, so you may want to double-check whatever code is setting that up.